# How to bind view model data to Kendo DropDownlist without using the html wrapper

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC5. The view takes a model from controller:

```
    public class IncidentWorkbenchViewModel
    {
        public List<string> ActiveUserList { get; set; }
    }
```

I figured out how to bind the list to Kendo DropDownList using the Kendo UI for ASP.NET wrapper in the following way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ActiveUserList)
    .BindTo(Model.ActiveUserList).Name("selectedUser")))
```

Now I am wondering how I can do the same without using the HTML helper. I think it's better for me to use javascript instead of wrapper for better code separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript equivalent is:

```
<input id="selectedUser" />
<script>
  var activeUsers= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ActiveUserList));
  $("#selectedUser").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: activeUsers,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id"
  });
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that the model needs to be converted to json object, lol!

Comment: Actually, I prefer to set the datasource read to point to an mvc controller action that returns my list in JSON format. Then you don't have to worry about loading all those lists into a giant viewmodel.

Comment: hmmm, I see. I am going to change my code. Thank you again for your tip.